# Access the instance type from a TypeScript static method

Tags: typescript

In a static method in a base class, is it possible to name the currently class's instance type?

Put another way, can you make this code type check:

```js
class Base {
  static addInitializer(i: (v: any /* What type would go here? */) => void) {
    // implementation is irrelevent
  }
}

class Dog extends Base {
  bark() {}
}

class Fish extends Base {
  swim() {}
}

Dog.addInitializer((dog) => {
  dog.bark();
  // @ts-expect-error
  dog.swim();
});

Fish.addInitializer((fish) => {
  fish.swim();
  // @ts-expect-error
  fish.bark();
});
```

Note the use of `// @ts-expect-error` before lines that should be a type error. They're highlighted as 'unused' because `v` has type `any` rather than the type I'm trying to name here.

[TypeScript playground link](http://%20https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GjABNiBJAOz3zBDwC8EAnACjwC5oWA3TsCgJ7QA9ACpoAdQAWuaFgEAHJAHcA9gFcQxaAHNV0KcwQB%20aKOEBKaAF4AfNG6q8xK2gwZhw6HgC2CkAg%20CBQ4%20KoU3jB4TEwIAdzBWOjQAL6oaaigkDAAIqo60AgAHljBxDDwEEhu0ABGYEwA1iyuaRlZUNAAYngQUoUlZRWIKMkQyr4tKG2oqHk6AHQk5FQ0dIysLMT5VnajGNuL9U0tANzJntAAAlgQALTFSsBYDzGqTMmHC%20OTFucpf1mPT6S1IlGoeFoDGYLBYADNelJdvYagiQT8fGcLl4bvdHghnq8mO9kmipAtjs1AQDzkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the static method generic and constrained by the `this` param of the static method you can make the type of the class that you call the static method on available. From there, just use the `InstanceType` operator, like so:

```js
class Base {
  static addInitializer<T extends new (...args: any) => Base>(this: T, init: (e: InstanceType<T>) => void) {
    // implementation is irrelevent
  }
}

class Dog extends Base {
  bark() {}
}

class Fish extends Base {
  swim() {}
}

Dog.addInitializer((dog) => {
  dog.bark();
  // @ts-expect-error
  dog.swim();
});

Fish.addInitializer((fish) => {
  fish.swim();
  // @ts-expect-error
  fish.bark();
});
```